# How to make a field read only dynamically, ie on xforms-value-changed events and other events?

Tags: xml, readonly, xforms, orbeon

On changing a value in a dropdown field, I want to make a field read only. As far my programming knowledge, we set a field read-only while binding the field. Is there any way to make a field read only depending on events?

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a solution that *doesn't require explicit event handlers*: you could use two sets of controls with one set read-only, the other set editable. To toggle between both sets, you can put each of the sets in a `xforms:group` with a `ref` attribute that controls if the group is displayed or not.

Here's an example with groups referencing mutually exclusive conditions. Depending on the value of the `selectedvalue` instance node, one of the groups is displayed. If the select1's itemset is more complex than just 1 or 0, you will have to adapt the XPath of the `xforms:group@ref` attributes.

```
<xforms:select1 appearance="minimal" ref="instance('main')/path/to/selectedvalue">
...
</xforms:select1>

<xforms:group ref="instance('main')/path/to/selectedvalue eq 1">
    <xforms:input ref="instance('main')/path/to/textinput" />
    <!-- more editable XForms controls, bound to main instance -->
</xforms:group>
<xforms:group ref="instance('main')/path/to/selectedvalue eq 0">
    <xforms:input ref="instance('read-only')/path/to/textinput" />
    <!-- more read-only XForms controls, bound to a read-only instance -->
</xforms:group>
```

This solution has the advantage that event handling isn't required at all (or, more precisely, the XForms engine does the event handling part itself; the `xforms:group`s act as "event listeners" on the instance value themselves). It's also possible to combine this technique with explicit event handling: using an `xforms:action ev:event="xforms-value-changed"` that issues a `xforms:setvalue ...` on the node that's observed by the `xforms:group@ref` attributes.